# Does Federated Key Have to be part of primary key in every federated table?

Tags: database-design, azure, primary-key, azure-sql-database, federated

When you use federations in SQL Azure do you have to have the `tenantid` as part of the primary key on every table? That would mean that all tables except maybe one tenant table would all have composite primary keys (one that is really the primary key and then adding in the `tenantid`).

That appears to be what it says in [this article](http://manishku.blogspot.com/2012/04/sql-azure-federation.html).